# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for my DAO

Tags: java, spring

i am using spring.xml for my controller and dao configuration. my spring-config.xml is as below:

```
<bean id="courseDao" class="com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.moodle.dao.CourseDao"
    init-method="setMoodleDataSource" depends-on="moodleAuthenticationDetails">
    <property name="adapterDataSource" ref="adapterDataSource"></property>
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
    <property name="announcementDao" ref="announcementDao"></property>
    <property name="roleDao" ref="roleDao"></property>
    <property name="logDao" ref="logDao"></property>
</bean>
```

i have a coursedao class in my project in the package com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.moodle.dao in the project name lmex-impl. but my spring config is not getting the class from a lmex-impl.jar. the spring-config.xml is on lmex-web project. and other thing is that he is showing me a wrong path in exception. the wrong name is `Lcom/platysgroup/lmex/adapter/moodle/dao/CourseDao;` instead of `com/platysgroup/lmex/adapter/moodle/dao/CourseDao;` the exception full stacktrace is as below:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet threw exception
>
> > org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
> >     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
> >     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
> >     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
> >     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/platysgroup/lmex/adapter/moodle/dao/CourseDao;
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
>
> org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:315)
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotation.........
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.platysgroup.lmex.adapter.moodle.dao.CourseDao
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)

please help me to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: You've asked 23 questions and haven't accepted any answer. If you don't pay back, the community won't help you that eagerly.

Answer (score 1):

A NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when the JRE can't find a class. In your case, it can't find the class Lcom/platysgroup/lmex/adapter/moodle/dao/CourseDao, which you most probably did not add to your classpath.

Comment: I have all dao classes which is in package of com/platysgroup/lmex/adapter/moodle/dao/, but in exception i am getting a Lcom/platysgroup/lmex/adapter/moodle/dao/CourseDao. in my bean tag the class attribute name is com/platysgroup/lmex/adapter/moodle/dao/CourseDao. than also its giving a exception NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Please do a clean build! Also search your project files for instances of "Lcom".

Answer (score 0):

The prefix 'L' indicates the instance of class. Please see [Field Descriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2). You should focus on finding issue with configuration of bean `courseDao` and check that its all dependencies are there in same application context.

Comment: I've also searched for info about this `L` and its meaning. Unfortunately your link doesn't work any more. I found information here: [Field Descriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2)